# The OutputPath property is not set for project When creating appx Bundle file for Packager project

Tags: uwp, package, bundle, desktop-application, appxmanifest

I am creating the bundle file for Windows Application packager project that is the intermediate project to combine my UWP and desktop application functionality. My project builds successfully but whenever I try to create the Appx bundle file it gives me following error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='AnyCPU'.
>
> This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform

I tried changing the output path and also my output seems to be present in the right directory. 
How can I get rid of this error by making changes?

Comment: The error info is saying that either it is due to the configuration or it is due to VS cannot find the right project. Can you check the configuration of your desktop project and also your UWP proejct to see whether they are target to the same platform? I would recommend that you set all your project to one platform to have a test first.

Comment: I did this change but it does not generate any package appx upload file.

Comment: I seems saw your another post that you are using only 32bit library. So the configuration should be x86 in my point of view. If it is possible actually I would recommend you create a new project, copy your content there and then build everything again with X86 as the setting.